# Populate Sticky Listview Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Data from mCalendarModel is used to populate the listview below via adapter.  The problem is only one month must must be displayed for all data corresponding to that year.  For example :

```
*Current result: 
 Header -> January 
  Item -> Series St Pierre

 Header -> January 
  Item -> Series St Pierre

 Header -> January 
  Item -> Series St Pierre

 Header -> February
  Item -> Series St Aubin 


Expected Result:

    Header -> January 
    Item -> Series St Pierre
    Item -> Series St Pierre
    Item -> Series St Pierre
    Item -> Series St Pierre
    Item -> Series St Pierre
    Item -> Series St Pierre
    Item -> Series St Pierre
    Item -> Series St Pierre
    Item -> Series St Pierre

    Header -> February
    Item -> Series St Aubin 
    ...*
```

Is there a way to display only expected result

```
    *mCalendarModel = new ArrayList<CalendarModel>();
    mCalendarModel.add(new CalendarModel("JANVIER", "Dimanche 2/01", "Series St Pierre", "22 km", "$1000", "course_trail","1","1"));
    mCalendarModel.add(new CalendarModel("JANVIER", "Dimanche 2/01", "Series St Pierre", "22 km", "$1000", "course_trail","1","1"));
    mCalendarModel.add(new CalendarModel("JANVIER", "Dimanche 2/01", "Series St Pierre", "22 km", "$1000", "course_trail","1","1"));
    mCalendarModel.add(new CalendarModel("JANVIER", "Dimanche 2/01", "Series St Pierre", "22 km", "$1000", "course_trail","1","1"));
    mCalendarModel.add(new CalendarModel("JANVIER", "Dimanche 2/01", "Series St Pierre", "22 km", "$1000", "course_trail","1","1"));
    mCalendarModel.add(new CalendarModel("JANVIER", "Dimanche 2/01", "Series St Pierre", "22 km", "$1000", "course_trail","1","1"));
    mCalendarModel.add(new CalendarModel("JANVIER", "Dimanche 2/01", "Series St Pierre", "22 km", "$1000", "course_trail","1","1"));
    mCalendarModel.add(new CalendarModel("JANVIER", "Dimanche 2/01", "Series St Pierre", "22 km", "$1000", "course_trail","1","1"));
    mCalendarModel.add(new CalendarModel("JANVIER", "Dimanche 2/01", "Series St Pierre", "22 km", "$1000", "course_trail","1","1"));
    mCalendarModel.add(new CalendarModel("JANVIER", "Dimanche 2/01", "Series St Pierre", "22 km", "$1000", "course_trail","1","1"));
    mCalendarModel.add(new CalendarModel("JANVIER", "Samedi 3/01", "Series St Aubin", "22 km", "$1000", "course_route","1","1"));
    mCalendarModel.add(new CalendarModel("JANVIER", "Samedi 2/01", "Series St Aubin", "22 km", "$1000", "course_route","1","1"));
    mCalendarModel.add(new CalendarModel("JANVIER", "Samedi 2/01", "Series St Aubin", "22 km", "$1000", "course_route","2","1"));
    mCalendarModel.add(new CalendarModel("JANVIER", "Samedi 2/01", "Series St Aubin", "22 km", "$1000", "course_route","1","1"));
    mCalendarModel.add(new CalendarModel("FEVRIER", "Samedi 2/01", "Series St Aubin", "22 km", "$1000", "course_route","2","2"));*






public void populateHeaderList(){

    SectionAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionAdapter(getActivity(), mCalendarModel,mLayoutInflator){

        private ViewHeaderHolder headHolder;

        @Override
        public int numberOfSections() {
            return mCalendarModel.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int numberOfRows(int section) {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public String getRowItem(int section, int row) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasSectionHeaderView(int section) {
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public int getSectionHeaderViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getSectionHeaderItemViewType(int section) {
            return section % 2;
        }

        @SuppressLint("InflateParams") 
        @Override
        public View getSectionHeaderView(int section, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;

            if (convertView == null) {

                vi = mLayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.header_row_field, null);

                headHolder = new ViewHeaderHolder();

                headHolder.mTextHeader = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.mTextHeader);

                vi.setTag(headHolder);

            } else
                headHolder = (ViewHeaderHolder) vi.getTag();

            headHolder.mTextHeader.setText(mCalendarModel.get(section).month);
            headHolder.mTextHeader.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.calendrier_vert));

            return vi;

        }

        @Override
        public void onRowItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int section, int row, long id) {
            super.onRowItemClick(parent, view, section, row, id);

            Intent intentFicheCourse = new Intent (getActivity(),FicheCourse.class);
            startActivity(intentFicheCourse);
            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);

        }

        @SuppressLint("InflateParams") 
        @Override
        public View getRowView(int section, int row, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi = convertView;

            if (convertView == null) {

                vi = mLayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.header_row_item, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.mTextDate = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.mTextDate);
                holder.mTextAddress = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.mTextAddress);
                holder.mTextDistance = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.mTextDistance);
                holder.mTextTarif = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.mTextTarif);
                //holder.mLDivider= (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.mLDivider);

                vi.setTag(holder);

            } else
                holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

            holder.mTextDate.setText(mCalendarModel.get(row).date);
            holder.mTextAddress.setText(mCalendarModel.get(row).title);
            holder.mTextTarif.setText(mCalendarModel.get(row).tarrif);
            holder.mTextDistance.setText(mCalendarModel.get(row).distance);

            return vi;
        }
    };

    mHeaderList.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try out expandable listView?

Create 2 arrays, one for months which you can use to populate the parent, second one for child which you can use to populate the children.

Also, you may keep the parent row always expanded and it will appear exactly how you desire.

Comment: but it won't have sticky header

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a sticky header? Do you want january to be always on top?